# brew install v8 : make: *** [out/Makefile.native] Error 127

Tags: makefile, homebrew, v8

When I used the command: brew install v8, I got the output as follows:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8/archive/3.19.18.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8-3.19.18.4.tar.gz
==> make dependencies
==> make native -j8 library=shared snapshot=on console=readline
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
              -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. -S.native  -Dcomponent=shared_library -       Dconsole=readline -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Darm_fpu=default -Darm_float_abi=default
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/Makefile.native] Error 127
```

I have install python through homebrew, so I cannot understand why it says: 'python: No such file or directory'

brew --config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: 2f6dc2694b6af3b827617cfabf8230d6013b137d
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.8.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.3
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
X11: 2.7.4 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: do you have /usr/local/bin in your PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Python is installed but may be is not in your path, you could add this to your PATH variable in your shell startup script like .bashrc

Temporal solution could be to run this inside your shell

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin
```